# GCP - Dataflow SQL - Cannot query over table without a filter over column(s) that can be used for partition elimination

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, partitioning

I'm trying to create a GCP Dataflow SQL Job that copies data between different regions from a BigQuery time partitioned table `events`, the table is partitioned by DAY of the TIMESTAMP column `ingest_time`, the source table `events` is also configured to require partition filter on queries,
The query that I'm using already have the filter on partitions and yet I keeps getting the error of partition filter missing.

This same query was working in the past and stopped working at the 28 of Nov 2023, while the table schema didn't change.

Query:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM bigquery.table.`sp_project`.`event_tracking`.`events`
WHERE ingest_time > "2023-12-11 12:13:10"
```

Partitioning config:

```
Table Type: Partitioned
Partitioned by: DAY
Partitioned on field: ingest_time
Partition expiration: Partitions do not expire
Partition filter: Required
```

Error Message

```
Error message from worker: com.google.api.gax.rpc.InvalidArgumentException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: request failed: Query error: Cannot query over table 'sp_project.event_tracking.events' without a filter over column(s) 'ingest_time' that can be used for partition elimination
```

I tried to run a SQL Dataflow job that copies the data from a BigQuery partitioned table using a timestamp column, the query includes the partition filter, and yet the jobs keeps giving an error that the partition filter is missing.

Comment: Can you open a GCP support ticket?